# Sql oracle left join only match single rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I need short sql to left join T2 on T1 only if single math

```
 T1      T2       Desired
F1  F2   F1  F2    F1  F2
1   A     A   RR    1  
2   B     A           2  UU
3   C     A   TT    3
4   D     B   UU   4  YY
5   E     C   VV    5  ZZ
           C   XX
           D   YY
           E   ZZ
```

Comment: if T2 have multiple rows then return empty F2 otherwise value of F2 right?

Comment: Are you trying to left join T1 to T2 on T1.F2 = T2.F1 so you can output T1.F1 and T2.F2 but only if there is one row in T2 that joins to T1, otherwise return null?  It is far from clear from your question.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: If T2 have multip rows return null, I dont know which operator to use, Im trying return only if one row in T2 that joins T1 otherwise return null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple `GROUP BY/COUNT` to count the rows per hit and a `CASE` expression to only output the value if the row count is <=1;

```
SELECT T1.F1, CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>1 THEN NULL ELSE MAX(T2.F2) END F2
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.F2 = T2.F1
GROUP BY T1.F1
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6d8e2/1).

Answer (score 1):

USING group by to eliminate the records with duplicates and doing left join to get all values from T1

```
   select T1.F1, ISNULL(T2.F2,'') from T1
    LEFT JOIN 
    ( 
      select F1 from T2
      group by F1
      having count(*) =1
    ) T
    on T1.F1 = T.F1
    LEFT JOIN T2
    on T2.F1 = T.F1
```